# Competing Python versions

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew

On my Mac, I have 2 versions of Python running, one from Brew (3.9) and another one (3.8)
When I try to install some data science packages via pip3, they are installed but cannot be used as 3.9 takes over.

python3 --version
Python 3.9.10

which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3

pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Library/Python/3.8/site-packages

python3

> > > import pandas
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

pandas is just one example of the many packages I see via pip3 freeze.

What are my options to point to installed versions at Python 3.8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to approach this:

1. One temporary option is to use `alias` like this:

   alias python3=python3.8
2. You can use directly `python3.8` in your terminal.
3. If you want to install the packages to `python3.9` then you can also use `pip3.9`
4. You could use:

   python3 -m pip install module

which will use `pip` to install to the python version you just used.

The [recommended way](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) is to use:

```
python3 -m pip install module
```

Comment: That fixed my most pressing operational issue, I can now work normally.  I identified though that I have 2 Python binaries with "which -a python", the working one is the Homebrew one "/opt/homebrew/bin/python3" and it works with pip packages installed under "/Users/my_ldap/Library/Python/3.9/bin"

Comment: I meant "python3 -m pip install module" fixed my issue.

Comment: @ozaarm that’s great. You can also accept the answer, if it helped in resolving the issue.

Comment: I have a similar situation, but with python 3.9 and 3.11. I figured out that I have two instances of python installed, which do not share the packages. Should I remove the folder and the frameworks for 3.9 completely if I'm not using them? Does it matter that I have multiple instances of packages installed?